# How does facebook/twitter update the status time have been posted?

Tags: javascript, real-time, settimeout, setinterval

Sorry if the title confuse you because my english kinda poor and also sorry for asking such a tedious question. When I open my facebook/twitter and I saw the time of the status have been posted updating from 1 min to 2 min and so-on automatically. So I try to open 2 broswer and to research does it update together at the same time.So yes it really do.My question is which technique does it use? Real time such as websocket/node.js or just simply use the setInterval/setTimeout function in javascript? I'm learning so hope anyone can teach me as well.

Comment: They probably use websockets, with all kinds of available fallbacks.

Comment: Are you really interested in the facebook and twitter sites specifically, or real-time applications in general? You could easily find out which technology(s) they've applied by using your browser's devtools (network inspector, specifically).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used the [timeago](http://timeago.yarp.com/) jquery plugin before to achieve the self-updating timestamps.

```
 <abbr class="timeago" title="2008-07-17T09:24:17Z">July 17, 2008</abbr>
```

if you put your full date in the title, it will keep updating the time.